# How to use Bootstrap4/ Scrollspy - without <body> tag

Tags: bootstrap-4

In Rails I can't set `<body>` attributes, so I have to follow the  [bootstrap4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/scrollspy/#how-it-works)  documentation:

**When spying on elements other than the `<body>`, be sure to have a height set and overflow-y: scroll; applied.**

But how would be looks like a examples that works ?

Here how my code looks like:

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <nav id="navbar-orders-now-status" class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#SECTION1">SECTION1</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#SECTION2">SECTION2</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#SECTION3">SECTION3</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>


        <div class="row" data-spy="scroll" data-target="#navbar-orders-now-status" data-offset="0" style="height: 300px; overflow-y: scroll;">
            <div class="col-12">

                    <h4 id="SECTION1">SECTION1</h4>
                    <table class="table table-sm">
                     ...
                    </table>

                    <h4 id="SECTION2">SECTION2</h4>
                    <table class="table table-sm">
                    ...
                    </table>

                    <h4 id="SECTION3">SECTION3</h4>
                    <table class="table table-sm">
                    ...
                    </table>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

What happens when I click on the the section3 link (for example), the focus jumps on the anchor postion section3, then the page is reloaded and the focus is set on the section1. 
Also when I scroll through the scrollable window, the section links will not be high lighted.

Comment: I found out that RAILS turbolinks is the reason why Scrollspy does not work. Now how I can use Scrollspy in cooperation with turbolinks ?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix it and move it to work. The following code runs within a RAILS 5 environemnt, without to modify the `<body>` tag.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-12">
    <nav id="navbar-orders-now-status" class="navbar" style="background-color: #ffeeb2">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#SECTION1" data-turbolinks="false">SECTION1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#SECTION2" data-turbolinks="false">SECTION2</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#SECTION3" data-turbolinks="false">SECTION3</a>
            </li>
            ...
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

```
<div class="row" data-spy="scroll" data-target="#navbar-orders-now-status" data-offset="0" style="height: 300px; overflow-y: scroll;">
    <div class="col-12">
        <h4 id="SECTION1">SECTION1</h4>
        <table class="table table-sm">
            ...
        </table>
        <h4 id="SECTION2">SECTION2</h4>
        <table class="table table-sm">
            ...
        </table>
        <h4 id="SECTION3">SECTION3</h4>
        <table class="table table-sm">
            ...
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```